# Role not showing up on Grant

Tags: 7, users

I have an issue with a new role I created. I created a role called "folders" and defined it in the module and AD, since we are using LDAP, however I can not see the role on grant. I have tried refreshing the browser, flushing all caches and logging in and out, but it does not show up on the roles list when I am trying to grant it.

Also I have checked that it has "show published content" checkbox checked

Please help me out what could be the issue and what to do to resolve it.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Belongs on the Drupal issue queue